# retrieve data from html code with vbscript

Tags: http, vbscript

I have a problem - I have an URL: like (http:://exampl.com/example) and when I open this page in browser I see a table with vertain values. Here is a HTML code:

```
<p>
<table>
<tr><td>RegistrationDTO.setUsername</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>RegistrationDTO.getLastName</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>RegistrationDTO.getPersonalNumber</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>RegistrationDTO.getFirstName</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>RegistrationDTO.register</td>
<td>1068</td>
<td>1068</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get the value from RegistrationDTO.register = '1068' (the first one) from this table.

How can I do this? Please help!

Comment: i need to use a vbscript to implement this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to get info from HTML. Both are demonstrated here:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const csURL             = "http://gent/16584664.html"                 ' 'real' const
Dim   csFSpec : csFSpec = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName(".\16584664.html") ' 'pseudo' const

' use comment or order to select a strategy
WScript.Quit useDom()
WScript.Quit useRegExp()

Function useRegExp()
  Dim sAll  : sAll      = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec).ReadAll()
  Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
  reCut.Global  = True
  reCut.Pattern = "RegistrationDTO.register</td>\s+<td>(\d+)</td>"
  Dim oMTS  : Set oMTS  = reCut.Execute(sAll)
  If 1 = oMTS.Count Then
     WScript.Echo "success:", oMTS(0).SubMatches(0)
  Else
     WScript.Echo "failure"
  End If
  useRegExp = 0
End Function ' useRegExp

Function useDom()
  Dim oDOM  : Set oDOM = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
' Dim sHTML : sHTML    = getURL(csURL)
  Dim sHTML : sHTML    = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec).ReadAll() ' for testing
  oDOM.write sHTML
  ' descending the tree                HTML          BODY         TABLE         TBODY       5th row       2nd col
  Dim oItem : Set oItem = oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(0).childNodes(0).childNodes(4).childNodes(1)
  ' WScript.Echo "success:", oItem.tagName ' drill down help
  WScript.Echo "success:", oItem.innerHTML
  ' WScript.Echo "success:", oItem.parentNode.childNodes(2).innerHTML ' verification
  useDom = 0
End Function ' useDom

Function getURL(sURL)
  Dim oHTTP : Set oHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
  oHTTP.Open "GET", csURL, False
  oHTTP.Send
  If 200 = oHTTP.Status Then
     getURL = oHTTP.responseText
  Else
     ' handle error
  End If
End Function ' getURL
```

output:

```
cscript 16584664.vbs
success: 1068
```

The RegExp approach obviously presupposes that you can define a pattern to uniquely identify the desired part. The DOM approach won't work with faulty HTML and may be clumsy if you have to get at the desired item by position (as in this case). Both are sensible to changes of the HTML.

**P.S.**

csFSpec is (the full path to) a file containing the given sample HTML wrapped in the necessary tags to make it legal. For testing, you can SaveAs the page from the browser.

If you set csURL to the correct URL and activate the getURL() line in the useDom() function, you don't need the file.

**P.P.S.**

To cope with the slightly different HTML Emil gave in his (probably soon to be deleted) other question, I had to change the RegExp pattern from:

```
reCut.Pattern = "RegistrationDTO.register</td>\s+<td>(\d+)</td>"
```

to:

```
reCut.Pattern = "RegistrationDTO.register</td>\s*<td>(\d+)</td>"
```

to deal with whitespace (more general and therefore better, should have done it from the start)

and the drill down from:

```
' descending the tree                HTML          BODY         TABLE         TBODY       5th row       2nd col
Dim oItem : Set oItem = oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(0).childNodes(0).childNodes(4).childNodes(1)
```

to:

```
  ' descending the tree                HTML          BODY             P        TABLE         TBODY       6th row       2nd col
  Dim oItem : Set oItem = oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(0).childNodes(0).childNodes(0).childNodes(5).childNodes(2)
```

to take an extra P and the changed number of rows into account.

This illustrates the fragigility of both strategies, I mentioned above. @Ansgar's way of looping over a (hopefully) stable collection and doing comparisons could be of help here.

Comment: In a both of the solutions I got an error! Can it be because of this reason: this is a Java web application

Comment: Please, can you help me, I get an error message! I dont know what to put in csFSpec : csFSpec! This page is made on Java! So it is looking like:
localhost:8081/register/monitor?command=getAllStats

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "http://example.com/example"
While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

For Each tr In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
  If InStr(tr.innerText, "RegistrationDTO.register") > 0 Then
    Set row = tr
  End If
Next

WScript.Echo row.children(1).innerText

ie.Quit
```

---

For troubleshooting, to check what the script actually sees, try something like this:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://example.com/example"
While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.OpenTextFile("C:\debug.html", 2, True).Write ie.document.body.innerHtml
```

Inspect `C:\debug.html` if it actually contains the table elements in question.

Comment: In a both of the solutions I got an error! Can it be because of this reason: this is a Java web application

Comment: Accodring to your solution:
It opens my page in IE, but then I get error:
Line: 5
Char: 1
Unspecified Error
Code: 80004005
Source: (null)

Comment: It writes File not Found Error

Comment: Sorry for long answering! I have tried your code and received one more error: Line 6 Char 1 Unspecified Error. Code 80004005 Source : null

Comment: The browser window should be visible after running the above code. Is the page actually loaded? Do you get the same result when you try `ie.document.documentElement.outerHtml` instead of `ie.document.body.innerHtml`? What is the output of `WScript.Echo TypeName(ie.document)`?

Comment: Yes, the page is opening and I see all the content! Then I see an error message, which I described you previosly. And in C:// the debug.html is created, but it is empty

Comment: The same error, when I use ie.document.documentElement.outerHtml

Comment: What is the output of `WScript.Echo TypeName(ie.document)`?

Comment: Excuse me, but where should I put this line?

Comment: Unspecified error Line 5 Char 1, just where I put WScript.Echo TypeName(ie.document)

Comment: What happens when you change the URL to `http://www.google.com/`? Do you get the same error?

Comment: I've tried to change URL to google.com, and it showed HTML Document in output, but then an error: Line 7 Char 1: Invalid procedure call or argument
fso.OpenTextFile("C:\debug.html", 2, True).Write ie.document.body.innerHtml

Comment: Replace `fso.OpenTextFile("C:\debug.html", 2, True).Write ie.document.body.innerHtml` with `WScript.Echo ie.document.body.innerHtml`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: I do not get any error message now! :) Now I've got thsi message: HTML Document and then web broswer with google is opening + windows script host with all the google html code

Comment: Then it seems your Java application does not generate a DOM document for some reason. In that case you're out of luck.